# Do I have to have LUN on a iSCSI Target?

Tags: linux, iscsi, lvm, lun

I am using Linux, and was wondering, if I could put LVM directly on a iSCSI target without a LUN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the iSCSI Target (iscsi server) presents a "disk" to a a client (initiator) it is presented as a SCSI LUN.  The LUN can then be imported into LVM and used however you want.

On the Reverse of this question can you present an LVM volume to a client as a LUN then yes.  You can create an LVM volume, or use an existing one and present that to the iSCSI clients.  But on the client side it will still be presented as a LUN

Answer (score 2):

[i]SCSI must identify a target with both ID and LUN. You tipically have three (or four) numbers to identify a target in [i]SCSI: controller number, [bus number,] ID number and LUN number.

If you have a single hard disk on a SCSI copper bus, the LUN of the hard disk is zero and is "transparent" for the user.

Don't confuse LUN with partition: partition is simply a logical area within a LUN.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Unit_Number

Answer (score 0):

But on the client side it will still be presented as a LUN you can create an LVM volume, or use an existing one and present that to the iSCSI clients